# Is it possible to draw object with outline and fill at the same time?

Tags: c#, skiasharp

I would like to draw a polygon for example, or draw a text in such way that the color of the outline is different than the color of the fill ("content"). I found out the property `ColorF` inside `SKPaint` and I guessed all it takes is to change style to `StrokeAndFill` -- well, I wrong guess, I got single color. In the following example the single color is `ColorF` (with `DrawText` it is `Color`).

Visually I can achieve the desired effect using two passes, but I wonder if this is possible with one step.

Example of drawing and filling polygon:

```
        using (var sk_paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.StrokeAndFill,
            Color = outline_color,
            ColorF = fill_color,
            IsAntialias = true,
            StrokeWidth = (float)thickness
        })
        {
            using (var path = new SKPath { FillType = SKPathFillType.EvenOdd })
            {
                path.MoveTo(points.First().x, points.First().y);
                foreach (var p in points.Skip(1))
                    path.LineTo(p.x, p.y);
                path.Close();
                canvas.DrawPath(path, sk_paint);
            }
        }
```

*As for lines I found it (RTFM ;-)) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/curves/effects#path-outlining I wonder if `ColorF` is not some sort of leftover. Anyway, I am still interested in drawing text with outline.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: you can't. Both color properties (`Color` and `ColorF`) of `SKPaint` set the same `SKColorF` value internally (`Color` being converted into `ColorF`). The 'F' in `ColorF` indicates the RGBA values are stored as floats instead of bytes.